# How to Update a table using transaction logs row by row using dynamic SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table which shows `Ticket ID` and its status and who is assigned to on a BI database. Here no duplicates and granularity is each ticket.

```css
Ticket_ID   Status  Assigned_To   Date
--------------------------------------------------
001         Open    Team A        01/01/2020 10:01
002         Working Team B        01/01/2020 10:01
003         Open    Team C        02/01/2020 18:50
004         ResolvedTeam B        02/01/2020 19:22
```

Now, there is a daily transaction log containing each change. However, column
changes are appearing as rows as below.

Daily transaction logs

```css
Ticket_id     Field_Name        New Value     Date
---------------------------------------------------------------
001           Assigned_to       Team B        02/01/2020 10:23
002           Assigned_to       Team A        02/01/2020 10:23
002           Status            Resolved      02/01/2020 10:24
003           status            Resolved      03/01/2020 10:24
004           Assigned_to       Team C        03/01/2020 13:50
004           Assigned_to       Team A        03/01/2020 13:51
004           Status            Resolved      03/01/2020 13:51
```

Now I want to write an update script using dynamic SQL script using a cursor (I guess it is the best method) to update the `Ticket` table based on the new values on the logs. I need SQL script to go row by row on transaction log table and update the `Ticket` table with the new values.

Expected output as below:

```
Ticket_ID     Status     Assigned_To  Date
------------------------------------------------------
001           Open       Team B       02/01/2020 10:23
002           Resolved   Team A       02/01/2020 10:24
003           Resolved   TeamC        03/01/2020 10:24
004           Resolved   Team A       03/01/2020 13:51
```

Comment: Why do you think you need either dynamic sql or a cursor? This is a simple set-based query. Are you really using two versions of sql server either barely or not at all supported?

Comment: @Stu I might be wrong I am getting daily logs from Oracle using OpenQuery. There are 9 types of different status changes not just 2. So it is complicated a bit than this. Thank you

Comment: I also don't understand why you would want a cursor here, you can do this in a single `update`. Does the `Date` column get updated also? And are all the relevant columns the same data type?

Comment: Fixed number of status changes  (column names) doesn't require dynamic. It's a regular sql, a bit verbouse although.

Comment: @Serg Yes, the date column get updated too. So, I might be wrong can you propose your suggestion please

Comment: @Charlieface yes date column get updated. We need to get the unique set for each Ticket and then Pivot it. I tried but didnt work. Then I thought, curser will work, better. If you can suggest that would be great. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Kind of

```
update t
set
   Status = case log.Field_Name when 'Status' then log.NewValue else t.Status end,
   ...
   Assigned_To = case log.Field_Name when 'Assigned_To' then log.NewValue else t.Assigned_To end,
   Date = log.LastDate
from tickets t
join ( -- take only last row for Ticket_id + Field_Name
   select top(1) with ties Ticket_id, Field_Name, NewValue, 
         max(Date) over (partition by Ticket_id) LastDate
   from DailyLog
   order by row_number() over(partition by Ticket_id, Field_Name order by Date desc)
  ) log on t.Ticket_ID = log.Ticket_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

So here's a solution you can use as a template, just amend for what other type of log actions you have.

First remove unecessary duplicates, leaving only the final status for each ticket, then pivot into a column for each property, and finally join to `tickets` to update.

Okay, so maybe not *that* simple, but no cursor required :)

```
with l as (
    select *, Row_Number() over(partition by Ticket_id, Field_Name order by [date] desc)rn
    from TransactionLogs
), u as (
select l.ticket_id,
    Max(case when field_name='status' then newvalue end) [Status],
    Max(case when field_name='assigned_to' then newvalue end) Assigned_to,
    /* Add additionalfield name properties here */
    Max(l.[date]) [Date]
from l 
where l.rn=1 
group by l.ticket_id
)

update t set
    t.[status]=IsNull(u.[status],t.[status]),
    t.Assigned_To=IsNull(u.Assigned_to,t.Assigned_To),
    /* Include additional columns here */
    t.[date]=isnull(u.[date],t.[date])
from u join tickets t on t.Ticket_Id=u.Ticket_id;
```

See [working fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/86da3/3)